# Return list items based on class and position

Tags: jquery, list, if-statement

I am working with unordered lists that are part of a hierarchical menu. I need to return list items based on their class and list position so that I can then make some programmatic css adjustments. Here is some sample HTML:

```
<ul class="category1">    
    <li class="sec secactive" secid="360007912231" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="null" style="display: list-item;"><a href="myURL">Section1</a></li>    
    <li class="sec subsec" secid="360008584672" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="360007912231" style="background-color: red; display: list-item;"><a href="myURL">Subsection A</a></li>   
    <li class="sec subsec" secid="360008585372" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="360007912231" style="background-color: red; display: list-item;"><a href="myURL">Subsection B</a></li>    
    <li class="sec" secid="360007910471" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="null" style="display: list-item;"><a href="myURL">Section 2</a></li>    
    <li class="sec" secid="360007155641" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="null" style="display: list-item;"><a href="myURL">Section 3</a></li>
    <li class="sec subsec" secid="360008585592" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="360007912231" style="background-color: red; display: list-item;"><a href="myURL">Subsection A</a></li>
    <li class="sec" secid="360007106191" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="null" style="display: list-item;"><a href="myURL">Section 3</a></li>   
</ul>
```

If you look at the sample HTML, you will see that every list item (`li`) has a class of 'sec'. In most cases a list item will have other class assignments too -- such as 'subsec'.

I am trying to put together some jQuery that allows me to programmatically target any 'subsec' list item that immediately precedes a list item that does NOT have the 'subsec' class assignment. So, if we look again at the sample HTML, I would want to be able to return the 3rd and 6th list items. (They both have a class of 'subsec', and they appear right before another li that does NOT have the 'subsec' class.)

Here is the jQuery I have tried, but it is not working properly. (It seems to be targeting ALL of the 'subsec' list items rather than just the ones I need to return.)

```
$("li.subsec").each(function() {
    if ($(this).next('li.sec') !='li.subsec');
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Any advice on how to fix my jQuery code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that you should use external CSS files to store your styling rules, not inline `style` attributes. In addition `li` elements are by default `display: list-item` so you don't need to explicitly set it.

With regard to the issue, you need to provide the `.subsec` selector to `next()` and check the `length` of the resulting jQuery object to determine if a match was found:

```
$(".subsec").each(function() {
  if ($(this).next('li.subsec').length == 0)
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
});
```

However this can be made more succinct by using `filter()` instead:

```js
$(".subsec").filter((i, el) => $(el).next('li.subsec').length === 0).addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo { background-color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="category1">
  <li class="sec secactive" secid="360007912231" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="null">
    <a href="myURL">Section1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sec subsec" secid="360008584672" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="360007912231">
    <a href="myURL">Subsection A</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sec subsec" secid="360008585372" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="360007912231">
    <a href="myURL">Subsection B</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sec" secid="360007910471" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="null">
    <a href="myURL">Section 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sec" secid="360007155641" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="null">
    <a href="myURL">Section 3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sec subsec" secid="360008585592" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="360007912231">
    <a href="myURL">Subsection A</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sec" secid="360007106191" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="null">
    <a href="myURL">Section 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As an aside, be careful adding non-standard attributes to your elements, such as `secid`, `categoryid` and `parentsecid`. They can cause issues in the UI and also with JS. I'd suggest using [`data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attributes if you want to store metadata in your HTML.

Comment: Thanks. Your code suggestion does work. Unfortunately (and strangely) I did not see it until I had already worked out another solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to check if `class` property (function [`prop()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_prop.asp)) contains `"subsec"` substring.

```
$("li.subsec").each(function() {
    if ( !($(this).next().prop("class").includes("subsec") ) )
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    else
        $(this).css("background-color", "green");
});
```

In this example I assigned a different color (green) to the element not matching the condition (in order to overwrite the style property in html section, which would have assigned red background color anyway).

The following image shows the result:

[image: siblings with different class]

Alternatively, you can check the presence of the class by issuing for the `next()` element the `hasClass()` method (which returns a boolean). In this way the check becomes

```
$("li.subsec").each(function() {
    if ( !($(this).next().hasClass("subsec") ) )
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    else
        $(this).css("background-color", "green");
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I tried your code but it is somehow not working properly for me. I checked the console and I am getting the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous>"

Comment: @Marconi Is your list the same as shown in your example?

Comment: @Marconi In my WAMP environment, with Firefox, it works also when subsec is at the end of the list.

Comment: The actual menu I am constructing involves multiple ULs, but the structure and class names are just as you see in my initial question. I have already implemented a bunch of code blocks / functions that successfully manipulate the lists so I am not sure why the code you provided is throwing an error.

Comment: @Marconi Go step by step. Before the `if` conditional insert some `alert`s: `alert($(this).next());`, `alert($(this).next().prop("tagName"));` and `$(this).next().prop("class");`.

Comment: yeah, i finally figured it out. i dropped the `.prop("class")` out of the expression and also used `has.Class` instead of `.includes` and it finally worked. thanks again for your input.

Comment: @Marconi So for some reason your environment doesn't support prop? Do we know we it works for me and not for you? I could add a note in my answer in order to make it complete.

Comment: I actually think the 'offending' code in your initial suggestion was the `.prop("class")` that I simply removed from the expression. While I also ended up using `has.Class` instead of `.includes`, I am not sure that `.includes` was the problem. Either way, I am good now. You helped. Thanks.

Comment: @Marconi Probably the reason is the browser not supporting prop() for some reason

Answer (score 0):

The following code does the trick for me:

```
$("li.subsec").each(function() {
 if (!($(this).next().hasClass("subsec")))
 $(this).css("background-color", "red");
 });
```